# Dynamic Customer Engagement Model

Tags: regression

I have a built an engagement model using Logistic regression uisng SAS. My approach was to identify the customers my company considers engaged, and then I built a model (using both engaged and not engaged customers) and predict "engaged"..  but the most important variables are 3 months variables (time spent on site in the last 3 months, distinct devices used in the last 3 months, etc...).. I have been challenged by the business who would like to have a Dynamic engagement model, basically they want to see the scores changing quite fast when a dramatic change happens (Price change, Special Event , Xmas etc).

At the moment, it will take the model I have , around 3 months to detect a change, which is a long period and won't be useful for the business. Could you please advise what's the approach to take in this situation? Are there any other techniques I could use here? Is Signal detection modelling , the right approach? What type of variables should I add to the model?

Your help would be much appreciated.

Thank You